# Ansible playbook fails with: no test named 'success'

Tags: ansible, jinja

I have an Ansible Playbook that is used to configure [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) on my Windows Laptop, having rebuilt my laptop recently I needed to run the playbook again, however it is failing with the following message:

```
The conditional check 'aptitude_installed is success' failed. The error was: no test named 'success'
  line 1

The error appears to have been in '/mnt/c/source/richardslater/workstation-setup/wsl/plays/wsl.yml': line 15, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:

  - name: ensure aptitude is installed
    ^ here
```

The [context](https://github.com/RichardSlater/workstation-setup/tree/master/wsl/plays) from the playbook is:

```
tasks:
- name: check if aptitude is installed
  shell: dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' aptitude | grep 'install ok installed'
  register: aptitude_installed
  failed_when: no
  changed_when: no

- name: ensure aptitude is installed
  command: apt-get -y install aptitude warn=False
  when: aptitude_installed is success
```

The output of `dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' aptitude | grep 'install ok installed'` is:

```
install ok installed
```

and `ansible --version`

```
ansible 2.2.1.0
  config file = /mnt/c/source/richardslater/workstation-setup/wsl/plays/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

and `pip show jinja2`

```
Name: Jinja2
Version: 2.8
Summary: A small but fast and easy to use stand-alone template engine 
written in pure python.
Home-page: http://jinja.pocoo.org/
Author: Armin Ronacher
Author-email: armin.ronacher@active-4.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: MarkupSafe
```

I'm not entirely sure how it ever worked, either that or something changed since I built this playbook, any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

You use pretty old ansible, maybe worth to try a new one. Although tests "succeeded" and "success" should be in 2.2 too.

But main problem I think it's `failed_when: no` in your task. It makes test `when: aptitude_installed is success` completely useless, it will be always `true` because `failed_when: no` marks all tasks as successful.

If you don't want to stop on task, but still to have an idea how it went, you should use `ignore_errors: true`, not `failed_when: no`. With `ignore_errors: true` you can both continue your playbook and inspect a real tasks results.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any clue of how your code once ran and produced the expected result. The `when` clause cannot be executed (as you found out from the error) and would anyway produce the reverse result you are expecting if I follow the underlying logic (install the package only when it is already installed). Moreover, your are in this simple case far from good ansible practice.

You should avoid using `shell` and `command` when there is an existing module that already does the job and manages idempotency for you. In present case, you can use the agnostic [`package`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_module.html) module or the specific [`apt`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html) (which I will prefer in my example since your playbook targets an Ubuntu install on wsl and a debian/ubuntu package anyway).

```
tasks:
  - name: Ensure aptitude is installed
    apt:
      name: aptitude
      state: present
```

The above will simply install `aptitude` unless it is already there in a simple easy single task.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error also and ended up here, reason is I think I was using another version of ansible on another computer so I changed the syntax to `when: sometest is success` because I got warnings before. Now on this computer where I run version `2.2.1.0` apparently this does not work at all, so I fell back on `when: sometest|success` instead and now it works.